# Load session using session id

Tags: session, sinatra, rack

I have a Sinatra application, in which one of the rules expect the URL to contain the session id (returned from a previously called URL). How to overload the session with the one referenced by the session ID?

```
use Rack::Session::Pool

get "example/:session_id" do
  sessionId = params[:session_id]

  # how to reload the session now, using the sessionId?

end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

### Session ID in Path

If you must use a session id from the path, you can use this hacky way

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

configure do
  use Rack::Session::Pool, :key => 'session_id'
end

get "/example/:session_id" do
  session.id = params[:session_id]
  session[:force_load] = 'force' # force session.load!()
  session.delete(:force_load)    # remove dummy value

  session[:count] = session[:count].to_i + 1
  session.inspect
end
```

### Session ID in Request Params

A supported way would be to set [`:cookie_only`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/75c68e6da577f1f976af7979e47d0c5c915f3a6c/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L275) option to `false` if you are willing to move `session_id` to a request parameter (query parameter or body parameter)

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

configure do
  use Rack::Session::Pool, {
    :key => 'session_id', 
    :cookie_only => false, # adds request params as source for session id
  }
end

# works with /example?session_id=
get '/example' do
  session[:count] = session[:count].to_i + 1
  session.inspect
end
```

Demo

```
$ ruby app.rb &> /dev/null  &

$ curl -i localhost:4567/example?session_id=

  HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
  Set-Cookie: session_id=2a06759c64c130bc45036076; path=/; HttpOnly

  {"count"=>1}

$ curl -i localhost:4567/example?session_id=2a06759c64c130bc45036076

  HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
  Set-Cookie: session_id=2a06759c64c130bc45036076; path=/; HttpOnly

  {"count"=>2}

$ kill %1
```